# Should I pre-populate an object's attributes, or do a DB call for each of its attributes?

Tags: php, design-patterns

I see two general ways of handling instances of classes in PHP.

Take, for example, that we have users in the system.

### Method 1

```
$user_id = 5;
$u = new User($user_id); // fills in any and all info from the database
echo $u->getName();
echo $u->getEmail();
```

### Method 2

```
$user_id = 5;
echo Users::getName($user_id); // makes a call to the database
echo Users::getEmail($user_id); // makes a call to the database
```

Implied in this approach is that I have a class `Users` that has the business logic related to users. It has direct access to a `User` class that can do CRUD operations by calling MySQL.

Comment: can you think of a single reason why the first option would not be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 3**

```
$user = UserDao::findById($id);
$user->getName();
```

I like this approach because you should separate the model from the factory that creates the model.

Comment: Ok, for inserting a user I would do `Users::insert($name)` which would in turn call `User::insert($name)`. How would this work in your Data Access Object + Factory approach?

Comment: @eoinoc $user->save() or UserDao::save($user) or $userDao->save($user)

Comment: I hope I can continue to clarify :) For business logic such as `isUserExpired()` I currently put this in `Users::isUserExpired($user_id)`. In your approach it could be `$userDao->isUserExpired($user)`? I think that means that `$userDao` would be responsible for the business logic.

Comment: $user->isExpired() is what I suggest. Because you will need that logic in more than one place.  @dqhendricks said exactly what was thinking.

Comment: @eoinoc no the DAO (data access object) would only handle db operations. you wouldn't consider things like save and find business logic right?

Comment: @eoinoc dao would get you the model, then you would run operations on the model, then doa would save the model if necessary. if you were running an activerecord pattern, the model could save itself.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a query to get each property is expensive if you are going to get every property anyway. So your method 1 or @Amir's neater approach would be a better choice in this case.
It's a trade off, get "everything" with one db access in case you need it versus storing lots of stuff in memory that you might not need. 
Your two approaches are get everything at once 
or get each as you need it.

There are in between options basically 
get it if you haven't got it yet, 
get "common" stuff always and other bits as and when you need them.

or a mixture always get this, and then the other bits if you haven't got them yet.

There's no hard and fast rule. you have to look at what operations are carried out on the object, and how concurrent they are. ie can session 2 change person1's attributes while session1 is looking at it. Will this result in error, confusion, or not matter.

Comment: Thanks. I used to "sometimes get everything". Problem was, I could never remember or properly track what was already set. That's how I later settled on `Method 2` as a sure-fire way of always requesting the data when I needed it.